# Load controller/models from Opencart root folder

Tags: php, opencart

I am working on a script that grabs all the category and product data from my opencart webshop. Since i use a application to run this script i can't use the MVC structure of opencart, the php script has to be located at the rootfolder of opencart.

```
<?php

   if (is_file('./admin/config.php')) {
      require_once('./admin/config.php');
   }

   require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
   //require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart/user.php');

   $application_config = 'admin';
   $registry = new Registry();

   $loader = new Loader($registry);
   //$loader->model('catalog/product');
   $registry->set('load', $loader);

   $config = new Config();
   $config->load('default');

   $config->load($application_config);
   $registry->set('config', $config);
   $registry->set('request', new Request());
   $response = new Response();

   $response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   $registry->set('response', $response);

   $registry->set('cache', new Cache($config->get('cache_type'), $config->get('cache_expire')));
   $registry->set('url', new Url($config->get('site_ssl')));

   $language = new Language($config->get('language_default'));
   $language->load($config->get('language_default'));

   $registry->set('language', $language);
   $registry->set('document', new Document());

   $event = new Event($registry);
   $registry->set('event', $event);

   if ($config->get('db_autostart')) {
      $registry->set('db', new DB($config->get('db_type'), $config->get('db_hostname'), $config->get('db_username'), $config->get('db_password'), $config->get('db_database'), $config->get('db_port')));
   }

   if ($config->get('session_autostart')) {
      $session = new Session();
      $session->start();
      $registry->set('session', $session);
   }

   if ($config->has('action_event')) {
      foreach ($config->get('action_event') as $key => $value) {
         $event->register($key, new Action($value));
      }
   }

   if ($config->has('config_autoload')) {
      foreach ($config->get('config_autoload') as $value) {
         $loader->config($value);
      }
   }

   if ($config->has('language_autoload')) {
      foreach ($config->get('language_autoload') as $value) {
         $loader->language($value);
      }
   }

   if ($config->has('library_autoload')) {
      foreach ($config->get('library_autoload') as $value) {
         $loader->library($value);
      }
   }

   if ($config->has('model_autoload')) {
      foreach ($config->get('model_autoload') as $value) {
         $loader->model($value);
      }
   }

   class Myclass extends Controller
   {

      function login($usr, $pwd)
      {
         if ($this->user->login($usr, $pwd)) {
            return TRUE;
         } else {
            echo('Error: Login failed.');
            die;
         }
      }

      function cleanPost($post)
      {
         $post = mb_convert_encoding($post, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
         $post = htmlentities($post, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
         return $post;
      }

      function getProductCount()
      {
         $this->model->load('catalog/product');
         $products = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts();
         print_r($products);
      }
   }

   $db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
   $registry->set('db', $db);
   $registry->set('user', new Cart\User($registry));

   $myAPI = new Myclass($registry);
   if ($myAPI->login('user','password')) {
            getProductCount()
   }

?>
```

This codesnippet let's me login and use the product.php file located at: opencart\admin\controller\catalog. But when i run the code I get an empty array. So my question is: How do i include all the models/controllers in a custom made script in the rootfolder, or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: The code stated above works. Somehow the language ID wasn't set. This can be fixed by using:**

```
$this->config->set("config_language_id",1);
```

Comment: try using  $this->load->model('catalog/product'); in getProductCount() function

Comment: Thanks for your reply @saylibhagwat, but sadly this won't work since the "this" object should be equal to the $registry variable and i'm working outside of the controller class of opencart. When i run '$this->load->model('catalog/product');' I get an fatal error: "Call to a member function getProducts() on null". Which seems worse then getting an empty array. Weird thing is that it does come into the function of the model only returns empty.